# How to align row entries when they do not take full columns to act like `justify-content: space-between`?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am looking to build an auto layouting grid, where I can just put stuff in and not worry about exact placement.

As I am testing out the setup with CSS Grid, I found out that if I lay out items in expected order then they the fill out the whole grid nicely.

But, if I switch them around, the contents get aligned to the left at all times, but I am looking to space them out pushing stuff to edges, just like `justify-content: space-between` does for [flexbox](/questions/tagged/flexbox). I want the result to respect the columns, though.

I played around with `justify-content: space-between` as I saw that Grid spec also takes that into account, but it messes up item column span and doesn't actually do what I want.

Is this even possible? Preferably without JS.

Here's a layout where I want for the pink and blue items to be aligned to the end of the row.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#dashboard {
  min-height: 70vh;
  
  background-color: lightgray;
  
  border-radius: 1vh;
  
  padding: 3vh;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, auto);
  gap: 3vh;
}

#table {
  height: 20vh;
  
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  
  grid-column: auto / span 12;
}

#graph {
  height: 20vh;
  
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  
  grid-column: auto / span 12;
}

#stat-x, #stat-y, #stat-z {
  height: 20vh;
  
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  
  grid-column: auto / span 4;
}

#stat-y {
  background-color: green;
}

#stat-z {
  background-color: blue;
}

#small-table, #filter {
  height: 20vh;
  
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  
  grid-column: auto / span 6;
}

#filter {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="table"></div>
  <div id="graph"></div>
  <div id="stat-x"></div>
  <div id="small-table"></div>
  <div id="stat-y"></div>
  <div id="stat-z"></div>
  <div id="filter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you cannot do this

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah, starting to think that's how it is. Okay, cool, will work around that.